# Simplification of Simple Logical Statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to simplify a statement.

I am stuck at this point:

$(\neg A \lor \neg B) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B)$

Is it possible to further simplify this?

I used DeMorgan's Law to get to this point from $\neg (A \lor B) \lor \neg (A \land B)$ which seems rather unimportant or somewhat of a sidestep in that it doesn't get me closer to a simpler form of the expression.

Comment: Try to understand for which values of A and B your formula holds (you only have 4 cases) and for which values it does not hold. Then ask yourself, what do you need for expressing this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that this expression is the same as:

$$\neg(A\land B)$$

By just writing the logic table for both expressions.